# XNA Collision Detection with BoundingBoxes

Tags: c#, collision-detection, xna-4.0, raytracing

We're building an FPS in XNA, and we're in the process of implementing collision detection.  Our walls are rectangular, so the BoundingBox class seemed like a good option, but it's axis aligned.  We'd really like to have non-axis aligned walls.  Most of the discussion we've seen says to use BoundingSpheres, but this doesn't seem like the best option because the walls are really just rotated rectangles.

We've managed to model the character's movement as rays, and we know that we should be able to translate these rays from world space to the axis aligned box space using a rotation matrix.  Unfortunately we think that something is amiss with this transformation because we seem to be colliding with invisible (or somehow larger) walls, and our ray generation works for floor intersections (which don't rotate [yet anyway]).  The only reason we're using rays is because they're easy to generate, should be easy to transform into the box's space, and we can use XNA classes like the Axis Aligned BoundingBoxes for the actual collision detection.

We've implemented it like this:

```
internal float? collide(Ray ray) {
  Matrix transform = Matrix.Invert(Transform);
  ray.Direction = Vector3.Transform(ray.Direction, transform);
  ray.Position = Vector3.Transform(ray.Position, transform);
  return new BoundingBox(new Vector3(-.5f, -.5f, -.5f), new Vector3(.5f, .5f, .5f)).Intersects(ray);
}
public Matrix Transform { get { return Matrix.CreateScale(size) * rotate * Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos); } }
```

Rotate is passed in the constructor and is formed with a call to Matrix.CreateRotationY(theta). The ray passed into collide is in world space.  Transform is also the matrix applied to our model for rendering.  This model is a cube which goes from (-.5, -.5, -.5) to (.5, .5, .5).

In any event, our question boils down a few things: Is there a better way to do collision detection for non-axis aligned boxes against rays? Is there a better way to do it than using rays? Are we just idiots with something obviously wrong with our code?  If possible, we'd like to rely as much as possible on XNA's classes (or at least code that's already been written), and not have to write much more than a wrapper class.

Comment: I can't really provide an answer, but these pointers might help. Here is how I have done this for my ray tracing project, http://github.com/danieljfarrell/pvtrace. (1) make AABB intersection code, (2) move AABB it into some arbitrary position in the scene with transformation matrices, (3) perform intersection in the coordinate frame of the box (i.e. so we can use standard AABB intersection code) by applying inverse transform to box AND to ray. (4) get intersection point in box frame, (5) apply forward transform to get intersection point in world frame. Elegant, but expensive? You tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your trying to rotate rectangles (2d) and keep collision detection, then I have an answer. When I learned Xna, I used rectangles. You could have lots of little rectangles in your texture rectangle and detect collision for each collision.

Comment: To clarify, our game is a 3D FPS.